# Плагин Video js как сделать чтобы можно было сменить качество видео?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, frontend

Плагин Video js как сделать чтобы можно было сменить качество видео?
Только пожалуйста, не кидайте мне всякие ссылки на GitHub, просто скажите. может какой-то класс задать и т д